# Looking for a camera below $1000

Tags: canon, camera-recommendation

I want to buy a new camera and lens.

I am not a professional photographer but I love photography, so I want buy a new camera. Currently I have a Canon EOS 1000D. It is a basic camera, that is why I want to change it.

My use is nature photography and wildlife photography. I travel a lot, so I'd prefer a camera below $1000.

And one more thing: what things should I be looking for, keeping in mind the nature and wildlife photography?

Comment: This implies that you currently only have the camera body and kit lens (the one that normally comes with the body, which I believe is an EF-S 18-55 IS). Is that correct, or do you also have other lenses?

Comment: now only i have only one lens

Comment: At the moment, this question is going to get closed pretty rapidly as it's not going to be useful for other people. Could you try and revise your question to explain what you're finding limiting about your current body? If you can't answer that, then (as chills42 has pointed out) upgrading your body is the wrong option.

Comment: i am not upgrading my body because that have only basic functions that why i am choose new body and lens

Comment: Upgrading a body only makes it easier to change things (and some of the more esoteric issues that some people want like a brighter viewfinder or 100% viewing, or interchangeable ground glass).  It doesn't make for better photos. Basic functions are the same on *all* cameras.  Better bodies are often *more* restrictive than the entry level bodies in their 'basic functions'.

Comment: @krish "Having only basic functions" isn't a reason for upgrading. Which functions do you think are available on higher levels bodies do you think will let you get better photos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“A boat is a hole in the water, surrounded by wood or fiberglass, into which one pours money”

It’s not hard to stretch this analogy to photography. It won’t be difficult to bump up against your price limit.

I’ve been doing outdoor photography for just over five years and moved to a DSLR about two years ago, so I’m just a couple steps ahead of you.

For wildlife, you should consider a telephoto lens. I have a Canon EFS 55-250mm. It’s a bit of a compromise I made as a beginner. A good lens, but 300mm  would come in handy.

Consider getting a macro lens. Shooting a moose from 100ft is quite a thrill, but they don’t stick around. You might end up shooting a lot of wildflowers in between the exotic animals.

Get a sturdy bag! You want one that will shelter your camera when it tumbles down a fifty foot cliff. Never mind how I know ;—)

Get extra accessories. Lens caps get lost. If you travel for an extended period a spare battery would her quite handy.

Comment: thank you for your information. 
if it possible to make $1000-$1200

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly recommend refraining from buying a different DSLR body if you already have one unless you have a specific reason, such as one of the following:

- Higher shutter speed
- Higher ISO options (better low light support)
- Switching sensor size (i.e. cropped sensor to full frame)
- Desire a new feature that is unavailable with your current body (like video)

There are certainly other reasons, such as higher MP, but in most cases, your images will be improved more by lens upgrades than body upgrades.